# New Attribute set Product page not displaying first half of the content

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view

I created new **attribute set** [ Wallposter ] & created **new product** with that attribute set.

in frontend , first half of the product page is not displaying , but 2nd half is displaying fine.

I done reindex, still not working.....

[New product with new attribute set link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/wall1.html)

[old product with old attribute set link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/spock.html)

**New product image :**

[image]

**Old Product image :**

[image]

Comment: is there any condition in view.phtml file?

Comment: @GopalPatel as previous developer worked on these, i did't know that they set conditions for this , please post your comment as answer.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find If there is any condition in `view.phtml` file.

**Path** : `app/design/frontend/YOUR_THEME/YOUR_PACKAGE/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

**As tab and other parts from view template are showing correctly.**

Comment: you just nailed it.......

Comment: Anyone help me @ https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/221316/57334